# django login using class based for custom user

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

here is my user model.

```
class User (models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # token = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

and here is my views for creating user

```
class UserView(APIView):

    def post(self,request):
        try:
            # RequestOverwrite().overWrite(request, {'token':'string'})
            user_data = UserDetailSerializer(data=request.data)
            if not(user_data.is_valid()):
                return Response(user_data.errors)
            user_data.save()
            return Response("user created successfully",status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            return Response("Error while creating user")
```

now what i want to do is to create a token when i post a user and that token is used later for login.
also i want to validate user if it exist in database then make user authenticate.

what should i do..?any suggestion

below is my serializers.py

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =  User 
        fields = ('id','username','email_id','password','is_deleted','created_at','updated_at')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'required':True,
                'error_messages':{
                'required':"Please fill this field",
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token creation should be realized in model **User**. You can set default value to token field.

Add parameter default to User model token field:

**token = models.CharField(default=tokenGenerator, max_length=50)**

**tokenGenerator** should be some function that returns some generated token.

Secondly **UserDetailSerializer** should be edited to get token if it's necessary but not **required**.

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # You can also provide this default function like in model field
    # for this token field
    # default=tokenGenerator

    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model =  User 
        fields = (..., 'token')
        extra_kwargs = ...
```

Now your model gets generated token for newly created User.

User should be auto logged in after registration but it's not that simple.

You need to specify how do you want to communicate with API. You want token so i guess that front should request api and token should be used from cookies.

If you send request from browser eg. jQuery you need to get response with **generated token** and save it in cookies. Your post response in DRF:

**return Response({'token': user_data.get('token')},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)**

And now you have some more steps:

- Attach token to every browser request which requests API
- Create authentication class to validate every request checks for correct token
- ...

Now, if you read this you realize that it needs some work. If you know that and you intentionally want to create this, you need to create mentioned view [authentication class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#example).

Else try to use libs like [oauth for django](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). That will provide you ready classes for token management.

Also as @Ken4scholars mentioned, try to use Django User model. It have good methods for validation etc. without make this done manually.

Comment: Good explanation, but it's actually not a great idea to link the token from the user. It is usually the other way round. The reasons are: 1. The user becomes too coupled with the Token authentication which isn't good because you should be able to swap authentication techniques without refactoring the user model. 2. A user can only have one token. Imagine a situation whereby your user is logged in a mobile app and browser that use the same token. Logging of the app will automatically log him out of the browser because token is destroyed.

Comment: Due to these reasons, the user is usually linked from the token, so that the user model knows nothing about the authentication model being employed and it can have several tokens. The same reason session keys are not stored in  the user model for session  authentication, instead the session instance links the user

Comment: I agree but it is a good way to know how it works starting from this point.

Comment: maybe. Note however that DRF already includes a Token model that points to the user and already has a view for issuing tokens to users - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#generating-tokens. Maybe a better place to start from

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, it seems you are defining a custom user that is not in any way connected the [Django auth user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User). It is a very very bad idea and will be difficult to get it work with most Django features. You can check out how to [customize the existing user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/) if you really need to.

As for user authentication, using the DRF Token Authentication, the flow is this way:

1. Client sends request to create user
2. If user is created successfully, it requests for an authentication token using the user's login and password
3. The backend verifies user's credentials and issues a token
4. Client makes subsequent requests with the token
5. If token expires or user logs out, repeat 2-4

Check out how to do these in DRF's [TokenAuthentication documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).

Your question is not very specific so I'm not sure what sort answer you are expecting but following these steps should get you going.